# Ionic ion-navbar trasparent

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have to succeed in making ion-navbar transparent.
I tried to put transparent, but it does not work.

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
        "ionic": "3.20.0",
        "typescript": "2.3.4",
        "electron": "^1.6.5"
    },
```

page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      {{show.title}}
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button class="appbarButton" *ngIf="target == 'tv'" ion-button icon-only (click)="selectCurrentEpisode()">
        <ion-icon name="skip-backward"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button class="appbarButton" *ngIf="target == 'tv'"  ion-button icon-only (click)="selectNextEpisode()">
        <ion-icon name="skip-forward"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button class="appbarButton" *ngIf="detail" ion-button icon-only (click)="changeFavorite()">
        <ion-icon name="{{ (detail.favorite == true) ? 'star' : 'star-outline' }}"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]

Comment: https://yannbraga.com/2017/03/16/how-to-transparent-header-ionic2/

Comment: https://codepen.io/tvial/pen/mJojJo

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to play with its opacity ? Try this :

HTML file :

```
<ion-navbar class="transparent-nav-bar">
   <ion-title>
      {{show.title}}
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

SCSS file :

```
.transparent-nav-bar {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried as you say, but I can not make the transparent bar.
To see the image below.

Comment: I just tried and it works fine. Try to inspect your element and be sure the CSS is not overrided by something else. Also make sure your selector is precise enough (maybe you should try with ion-navbar.transparent-nav-bar).

Comment: I do not understand it's not working, how do I do the inspection?
I'm using it on a physical device, not on a browser.
Then the theming does not seem to support the rgba like this: "#0f000000".

Comment: Then it is better to put it on ion-header or ion-navbar, see code above.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a custom color in your `src/theme/variables.scss` file by adding a property in the $colors map and then call it like this.

```
<ion-navbar color="custom">
```

Comment: I'm trying directly in the app / app.scss, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Then it does not have to be a color must be seen, image below.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs//theming/theming-your-app/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.1/api/components/navbar/Navbar/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find the right class try this:

```
.toolbar-background.toolbar-background-md{
     background-color: transparent;
}
```